# breaking While True loop in x minutes

Tags: loops, dataframe

I am trying to find a way to break a while true loop after x minutes, below is my code. And appending the new data into dataframe via i() function

```
import time
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

price=[]
pricetime=[]


r=requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY?p=SPY&.tsrc=fin-srch')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
current_price = soup.find_all('div',{'class':"My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)"})[0].find('span').text

def i():
    while True:
        print(current_price + str(time.ctime()))
        price.append(current_price)
        pricetime.append(time.ctime())
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: I feel like a Python tag would have been appropriate, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use threading module with a timeout [1]:

1. init an Event object stop_event, and in each loop, check whether this stop_event.is_set().
2. init a Thread object thread_i, and pass your own function as the target.
3. start the thread_i and wait (join) it for 10 minutes.
4. set the stop_event to make your function stop.

The final code would be like this:

```
from threading import Thread, Event
import time

# Event object used to send signals from one thread to another
stop_event = Event()

def i():
    """
    Function that should timeout after 10 mins.
    """
    while True:
        # move your code here

        # Here we make the check if the other thread sent a signal to stop execution.
        if stop_event.is_set():
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # We create another Thread, set the target to be your function.
    i_thread = Thread(target=i)

    # Here we start the thread and we wait 10 mins before the code continues to execute.
    i_thread.start()
    i_thread.join(timeout=10*60)

    # We send a signal that the other thread should stop.
    stop_event.set()
```

[1] https://dreamix.eu/blog/webothers/timeout-function-in-python-3

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. So basically, we are running 2 threads, one for the webscrapping, the other 1 for timer. And once timer hit x minutes, it will send signal to kill both threads?